# Does a point on an affine curve have to be non-singular for the local ring to be integrally closed?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am not sure how the non-singularity requirement would come into the following argument: Suppose $\mathcal{C}_f$ is an irreducible affine curve with local ring $\mathcal{O}_P$ at a general point $P$ and field of fractions $k(\mathcal{C}_f)$. Suppose $u\in k(\mathcal{C}_f)$ with $u$ integral over $\mathcal{O}_P$. i.e. $u^n+a_1u^{n-1}+\cdots +a_n=0$ with $a_i\in \mathcal{O}_P$. We can write $u=\frac{p}{q}$ with $p,q\in\mathcal{O}(\mathcal{C}_f)$ and $p,q$ having no common factor. Then we have $\frac{p^n}{q}\in\mathcal{O}_P$. If $p^n,q$ have a common factor they must have an irreducible one and this must also divide $p$, so they don't. i.e. $q(P)\ne 0$ and hence $u\in \mathcal{O}_P$.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $k(C_f)$ is a UFD.

Comment: Er, I mean $\mathcal{O}(C_f)$. Notational variation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This follows from the fact that for a Noetherian local domain of dimension $1$, being integrally closed is **equivalent** to being a DVR. See Proposition 9.2 of Atiyah-Macdonald.

**Edit:**  Let $X$ be your curve, $P$ any point, and $\zeta$ the generic point. The problem with your argument is you seem to be assuming that you can write a fraction $p/q \in \mathcal{O}_{X,\zeta}$ with $p,q \in \mathcal{O}_{X,P}$ in its ***lowest terms***. That is, you're assuming that $\mathcal{O}_{X,P}$ is a UFD. This of course need not be true, because of the following fact:

> > **Proposition:** Let $A$ be a Noetherian local domain of dimension $1$. Then $A$ is a UFD if and only if it is a DVR.

**Proof:** Suppose $A$ is a DVR. In particular, it is a PID and thus is UFD. For the converse, suppose $A$ is a UFD. Let $\mathfrak{m}$ be the maximal ideal of $A$. Choose any element $x \in \mathfrak{m}$. By factoring $x$ into primes, we see that at least one prime factor of $x$ is in $\mathfrak{m}$. By maximality of $\mathfrak{m}$, we conclude that $\mathfrak{m}$ is principal, generated by $t$ say. It is now easy to see that every element $a \in A$ is equal to $ut^n$, where $u$ is a unit an $n \in \Bbb{Z}$ is unique. Hence the map $\nu : A \to \Bbb{Z} \cup \infty$, $a \mapsto n$ is a discrete valuation and the result follows.

Comment: I take your point. I was really asking what is wrong with the above general argument if $P$ happens to be singular.

Comment: @NoelRobinson I've edited my answer.

Comment: That is very helpful. I accept that if $P$ is non-singular then $\mathcal{O}_P$ is a DVR. What would really finish the story would be an example of a singular point where $\mathcal{O}_P$ was not a UFD. Do you happen to know one?

Comment: @NoelRobinson Take $X$ to be the curve $y^2 = x^3$. The local ring at the origin is $k[x,y]/(y^2 - x^3)_{(x,y)}$. This is not a UFD simply because $x,y$ are prime elements in the ring and (prove!) $y^2$, $x^3$ are two **different** factorizations of the same element.